# How to retrieve all the entries with hash key as a particular pattern in dynamo DB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-retrieval

I am new to amazon web services. I want to retrieve all the entries in the dynamo DB table which have a particular word in their hash key. It is similar to using like operator in oracle DB. How can I do it? If its not possible, how do I retrieve all the entries in the table without giving any constraint on the hash key so that later I can iterate over all of them to match the word?

Answer (score 16):

#### General DynamoDB thoughts:

Please, do not think of DynamoDB as you would of MySQL. DynamoDB is *only* a key:value store with a couple of niceties.

The fundamental of key:value store is:

> Either you know the key, and get your value;
>
> Either you don't, and you get the whole table.

In DynamoDB specific case, you can

1. Retrieve an item knowing the whole key with **`GetItem`**
2. Retrieve all items under a given **`hash_key`**, possibly applying a filter, with **`Query`**
3. Retrieve the whole table, possibly applying filters, with **`Scan`**

This said, `Scan` is both *slow* and *expensive*. You should never use it otherwise your design is most probably wrong.

#### Specific to your question:

In your case, it sounds like you will want to split your key into a

- `hash_key`
- `range_key`

Then you could use `Query` to get all the items sharing `hash_key`. With `Query`, you may apply filters like `BEGINS_WITH` to narrow you scope.

Please note that all (`hash_key`, `range_key`) tuples needs to be unique.

Comment: It should be worth mentioning that even if you do a query, and want to apply a filter within the query - the results can only be a max of 1MB, meaning that if the query exceeds 1MB, you will have have all of your data to be filtered on.

Comment: Makes me wish AWS and blogs didn't market DynamoDB as a 'not only SQL' datastore.  I've never worked with any key value store where you couldn't ask for the list of keys.  In their documentation I've not seen a head-nod to the requirement for maintaining your keys in another table/lookup.  @yadutaf's comment on Scans is spot on--it's almost like they added that feature so you can know when you're using the wrong datastore.